# How to loop a paragraph list (entity reference revisions list) in twig drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8, paragraph

How to loop a list of paragraphs and get each field values?

I've built a paragraph that includes other paragraphs.
Now i need to go trough them and get their values to list them into a twig template

Imagine structure of paragraph has this fields

1. title
2. description
3. paragraph:

   1. Title
   2. Description
   3. Start date
   4. End date

My *field.html.twig* file looks like

```html
{% if label_hidden %}
  {% if multiple %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <div{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</div>
  {% if multiple %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.content }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if multiple %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

My *paragraph--name.html.twig* looks like

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>{{ content.field_skill_title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ content.field_skill_description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
    {# HERE SHOULD GO THE LOOP WITH REST 3 PARAGRPAHS #}
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how should i implement the loop to display the values into template?

Comment: Your question is bit unclear to me. What's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>{{ content.field_skill_title }}</h2>
      <p>{{ content.field_skill_description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
    {# HERE SHOULD GO THE LOOP WITH REST 3 PARAGRPAHS #}
    {% for key, item in content.field_name_here if key|first != '#'%}
     {{ item['#paragraph'].field_title[0].value|raw }}
     {{ item['#paragraph'].field_description[0].value|raw }}
     {{ item['#paragraph'].field_start_date[0].value|raw }}
     {{ item['#paragraph'].field_end_date[0].value|raw }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you share a code, please try to explain your way in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alvins answer is still good, but Twig will now error with the inline "if" statement. Same concept, but need to separate the key check:

```
{% for key, item in content.field_name_here %}
    {% if key|first != "#" %}
      ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```